# NameError: name 'PartialState' is not defined error while training hugging face wave2vec model

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

Here is the code block which caused the error

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="my_awesome_mind_model",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=3e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    warmup_ratio=0.1,
    logging_steps=10,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="accuracy",
    push_to_hub=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset["train"],
    # eval_dataset=encoded_minds["test"],
    tokenizer=feature_extractor,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()
```

getting the following error

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in <cell line: 1>()
> 1 training_args = TrainingArguments(
> 2     output_dir="my_awesome_mind_model",
> 3     evaluation_strategy="epoch",
> 4     save_strategy="epoch",
> 5     learning_rate=3e-5,
>
> 4 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/training_args.py in _setup_devices(self)
> 1629             self._n_gpu = 1
> 1630         else:
> 1631             self.distributed_state = PartialState(backend=self.ddp_backend)
> 1632             self._n_gpu = 1
> 1633         if not is_sagemaker_mp_enabled():
>
> NameError: name 'PartialState' is not defined

I am trying to follow the audio classification guide of hugging face([link](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/audio_classification) on another dataset but upon running the training args code i am getting name "PartialState" not defined error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of 2023-05-11:

The error seems to be caused by an [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/22816) in the `huggingface/accelerate` library.

You can try following solutions:

#### Reinstall transformers & accelerate

```bash
pip uninstall -y transformers accelerate
pip install transformers accelerate
```

If you are using colab/Jupyter, **make sure to restart the notebook's Runtime**.

#### Install dev version of accelerate

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate
```

#### Reverse to previous version of transformers (4.28.0)

```bash
# You might also need to uninstall transformers first: pip uninstall -y transformers
pip install transformers==4.28.0
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, just restarting my colab notebook's Runtime solved the problem.

Comment: falling back to 4.28.0 worked for me

Answer (score 2):

pip install --upgrade accelerate and restart your notebook's runtime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).